# Find difference between three timestamps which are not in format that date command accepts

Tags: linux, bash, date, unix, awk

I have a file that has three different timestamps like below. (I have just put two lines here. The file has thousand of lines like them.)

```
blah!blah!20190206 12:59:03:579 PM!blah!20190206 12:59:03:691 PM!blah!20190206 12:59:06:422 PM!blah!blah
blah!blah!20190206 12:59:06:510 PM!blah!20190206 12:59:06:534 PM!blah!20190206 12:59:06:928 PM!blah!blah
```

I am trying to find the difference between each timestamp in every line.

With the below awk command,

```
awk -F! 'BEGIN{OFS="!";} {print $3, $5, $7}' | columnt -t -s "!"
```

I am able to extract the time stamp like below.

```
20190206 12:59:03:579 PM  20190206 12:59:03:691 PM  20190206 12:59:06:422 PM
20190206 12:59:06:510 PM  20190206 12:59:06:534 PM  20190206 12:59:06:928 PM
```

Now, first the problem is these timestamps are not in a format ready to be passed to the date command.

```
$ date -d "20190206 12:59:06:510 PM" +%s
date: invalid date '20190206 12:59:06:510 PM'
$ date -d "20190206 12:59:06,510 PM" +%s+%3N
1550080746+510
$
$ date -d "20190206 12:59:06,536 PM" +%s+%3N
1550080746+536
$
$ echo $(( `date -d "20190206 12:59:06,510 PM" +%s+%3N` - `date -d "20190206 12:59:06,536 PM" +%s+%3N` ))
$ 1046
$
```

The third colon needs to be replaced with comma inorder to be passed to the date command.

Second, how do I get the output like below with the difference between timestamps in each line printed along with the timestamps. So, I can glance through the output and find which line took more time.

```
20190206 12:59:03:579 PM  20190206 12:59:03:691 PM  20190206 12:59:06:422 PM 
 (difference between first and second column)  (difference between second and third column)
20190206 12:59:06:510 PM  20190206 12:59:06:534 PM  20190206 12:59:06:928 PM 
 (difference between first and second column)  (difference between second and third column)

20190206 12:59:03:579 PM  20190206 12:59:03:691 PM  20190206 12:59:06:422 PM 
 112 milliseconds  2731 milliseconds
20190206 12:59:06:510 PM  20190206 12:59:06:534 PM  20190206 12:59:06:928 PM 
 24 milliseconds 394 milliseconds
```

Comment: Please check the millisecond values in your expected output. They're either wrong and need to be corrected or you need to explain how those values are to be derived.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `date` can't read the input, use `sed` to format the input to the format it can read.

```
cat <<EOF >file
blah!blah!20190206 12:59:03:579 PM!blah!20190206 12:59:03:691 PM!blah!20190206 12:59:06:422 PM!blah!blah
blah!blah!20190206 12:59:06:510 PM!blah!20190206 12:59:06:534 PM!blah!20190206 12:59:06:928 PM!blah!blah
EOF

# remove the blah! words to leave only timestamps
# so we have: '20190206 12:59:03:579 PM!20190206 12:59:03:691 PM!20190206 12:59:06:422 PM'
<file cut -d'!' -f3,5,7 
# substitute the parts ':123 ' into '.123 ' so that date knows it's miliseconds
# now we have '20190206 12:59:03.579 PM!20190206 12:59:03.691 PM!20190206 12:59:06.422 PM'
sed 's/:\([0-9]\{3\} \)/.\1/g' |
# read the dates - they are still separated by `!`
while IFS='!' read -r d1 d2 d3; do
    # convert dates into seconds since epoch
    s1=$(date --date="$d1" +%s.%N)
    s2=$(date --date="$d2" +%s.%N)
    s3=$(date --date="$d3" +%s.%N)
    # compute differences
    diff21=$(bc <<<"scale=100; $s2 - $s1")
    diff32=$(bc <<<"scale=100; $s3 - $s2")
    # nice looking printf - I leave it to OP to extract only miliseconds and such
    printf "%.3f %.3f\n" "$diff21" "$diff32"

done
```

willl output:

```
0.112 2.731
0.024 0.394
```

As lastly I am a fun of `xargs`, here's the same using `xargs`:

```
<file cut -d'!' -f3,5,7 | 
sed 's/:\([0-9]\{3\} \)/.\1/g' |
# substitute `!` for a newline
tr '!' '\n' | 
# run date on each input line converting to seconds
xargs -i date --date={} +%s.%N |
# prepare for bc
xargs -n3 sh -c 'printf "%s-%s\n%s-%s\n" "$2" "$1" "$3" "$2"' -- |
# compute differences for each line
xargs -n1 sh -c 'bc <<<"$@"' -- |
# nice looking printf
xargs -n2 printf -- "%.3f %.3f\n"
```

and it looks neater.

Comment: Nice, though this could probably be boiled down to about half a dozen iines of GNU Awk (which has a convenient [`mktime` extension).](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html)

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk for time functions:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="!"; OFS="  " }
{
    numTs = 0
    for (i=3; i<=7; i+=2) {
        split($i,t,/[[:space:]:]/)

        date = gensub(/(.{4})(.{2})/,"\\1 \\2 ",1,t[1])
        time = ( t[2] + ( (t[6] == "PM") && (t[2] < 12) ? 12 : 0 ) ) " " t[3] " " t[4]
        secs = mktime(date " " time)

        ts[++numTs] = $i
        ms[numTs] = (secs * 1000) + t[5]
    }
    print ts[1], ts[2], ts[3]
    print " " (ms[2] - ms[1]) " milliseconds", (ms[3] - ms[2]) " milliseconds"
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
20190206 12:59:03:579 PM  20190206 12:59:03:691 PM  20190206 12:59:06:422 PM
 112 milliseconds  2731 milliseconds
20190206 12:59:06:510 PM  20190206 12:59:06:534 PM  20190206 12:59:06:928 PM
 24 milliseconds  394 milliseconds
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the output in seconds? Like the answer from Kamil Cuk

Comment: Yes it's trivial and I don't think the code's so hard to read that you can't figure out how to do that for yourself given a few seconds thinking about it. Give it a try and ask if you have any questions.